# DropdownButtonHideUnderline custom height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a DropdownButtonHideUnderline in my AppBar.  I adjusted the color of its container to stand out from the AppBar.  I would also like to adjust its height to be less then the AppBar (small padding around the text):

[image]

Here is my code:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    if (widget.appState.isLoading)
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    else
      return DefaultTabController(
        length: 5,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Home"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    isDense: true,
                    value: widget.appState.user.accountNumbers[widget.appState.selectedAccountIndex],
                    items: widget.appState.user.accountNumbers.map<DropdownMenuItem>((accountNumber) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(                                            
                        child: Text(
                            accountNumber,
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                            ),
                        value: accountNumber,
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (selectedItem) => setState((){
                      widget.appState.selectedAccountIndex = 
                        widget.appState.user.accountNumbers.indexOf(selectedItem);
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                ...
              ),
            ],
            bottom: TabBar(
              ...
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
                  ...
                ),
        ),
      );
  }
```

Comment: Wrap it in a Padding widget to get padding. But it's not entirely clear what your question is....

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your text widget inside DropdownMenuItem with Container.

```
//inside DropdownMenuItem
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,),
  child: Text(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints @rmtmckenzie and @yashthakkar1173.  What I needed to do was to wrap DropdownButtonHideUnderline in a Container with padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 17.0).  That did the trick.